# How to solve ReflectionException?

Tags: magento2, exception

I am completely new to magento and trying to install product recommendations module. Prior to that I tried installing its dependencies i.e saas_export and data_services modules.

But when I access store front it gives me the following exception.

```
ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist in 
/var/www/html/magento_1/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:24 
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/html/magento_1/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(24): ReflectionClass->__construct() 
#1 /var/www/html/magento_1/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(54): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() 
#2 /var/www/html/magento_1/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() 
#3 /var/www/html/magento_1/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() 
#4 /var/www/html/magento_1/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(237): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() 
#5 /var/www/html/magento_1/pub/index.php(28): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication() 
#6 {main}
```

Tried disabling the modules but then it says page is not working. Not able to solve. Any help on that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run `setup:di:compile` command. It's due to the interceptor class does not exist yet. Any module changes you need to recreate the interceptor class.

Comment: Tried running that command. Have following fatal error now.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\DataExporter\Config\ConfigInterface in /var/www/html/magento_1/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50

Comment: Try to remove the files under `generated` and `var` folder, then rerun this

Comment: I tried running, now i have this issue.

Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Wishlist\Block\AbstractBlock in /var/www/html/magento_1/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121

Comment: Any solution to this would be really helpful. Thanks.